# How to add graphs into Hudson

Tags: java, hudson

I have a project that requires the Hudson to run certain builds on a daily basis, and I want to make a line graph that shows the historical data of that build. I've searched on the google and there's seem to be few documentation how to do it. Can someone provide some information on this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "historical data"? Whether the build passed/failed? Time taken for the build? Test failures? Temperature of the build machine? Phase of the moon at build time?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Hudson Plo](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plot+Plugin)t plugin

Comment: I found the plugin, thanks. BTW, do you know how to add multiple graph into one padge? Whenever I want to add new data series file (.csv files), it only let me use one..

Comment: is there a help for how to use plot plugin? I installed it, but I don't know how to let the graph show.